# Scheme Continuation: What's the difference between call 'call/cc' in top level and non-top level?

Tags: scheme, racket

This code works as expected:

```
(define saved #f)
(cons 'wo (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! saved k) '())))
(saved 'ca!)
```

output (Racket console):

```
'(wo)
'(wo . ca!)
```

But when I wrap it in a function and call it, the program never stops. Why?

```
(define (test)
    (define saved #f)
    (cons 'wo (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! saved k) '())))
    (saved 'ca!))

(test)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A continuation is all that's left to be done in the execution context where it's saved.

In the first case, the continuation is saved when calling `cons`, so it's just to cons 'wo to something and return to the REPL.

In the second case, you call procedure `test`, so the continuation is *both*

1. cons 'wo to something
2. call the procedure bound to `saved` (i.e. the continuation) with 'ca!

so the continuation calls itself, hence the loop.