# Why don't Scheme continuations extend beyond function boundaries?

Tags: scheme, continuations

If a continuation captures the rest of a computation, why doesn't the following snippet of Scheme code enter into an infinite loop?

```
(define cont #f)

(define (funny1)
    (print "entered funny")
    (call/cc (lambda (k) (set! cont k)))
    (print "left funny"))

(funny1)
(print "end")
(cont)
```

It seems like returning from the function and calling 'print' and 'cont' should be part of the rest of the computation, triggering an infinite loop. Instead, it simply prints: "entered funny", "left funny", "end", "left funny"

The following CPS transformation of the previous snippet does, indeed, enter an infinite loop as expected:

```
(define cont #f)

(define (funny2 ret)
    (print "entered funny")
    (let ((rest (lambda ()
                    (print "left funny")
                    (ret))))
        (set! cont rest)
        (rest)))

(funny2 (lambda ()
            (print "end")
            (cont))))
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: This has to do with the top-level. If you put the code inside a function `(define (main) (funny1) (print "end") (cont))` and then call it `(main)` it *will* loop.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339956/scheme-continuation-whats-the-difference-between-call-call-cc-in-top-level-a

Comment: Also consider looking at [delimited continuations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29838344/465378), which generalize the idea of continuation capture.